# Adjusting my arrows in an inverted triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am in document class book and here is my drawing of a triangle:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\arrowL}{
    \tikz \draw[latex-] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}
\newcommand{\arrowR}{
    \tikz \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate= -90]
        \draw (0,0)--(0,2) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowR};
        \draw (0,2)--(2,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (0,0)--(2,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \node[left] at (0,0) {$v_3'$};
        \node[above] at (0,2) {$v_0$};
        \node[below] at (2,0) {$v_1'$};
        \node[above] at (1,1) {$a$};
        \node[above] at (1,-0.2) {$b$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I have the following problems in the direction of the arrows, I need my arrows to be as follows left arrow from $v_0$ to $v_3',$ up arrow from $v_1'$ to $v_3'$ and down arrow from $v_0$ to $v_1'.$

Could someone help me in adjusting these arrows please?

Comment: this is the fourth question on triangle with arrows -- you need to breakdown the code and experiment--this is the only way to learn

Comment: it seems like when we invert a triangle, the arrows should be adjusted somehow, I tried to understand this but I failed. My questions was related to really different parts. Though thanks for your advice, I will keep this in my mind @jsbibra

Comment: You forget something in your preamble. Insert all your code please!

Comment: Ok, I will, what thing did I forget @RaffaeleSantoro?

Comment: @Brain All your preamble!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I edited my code now, I hope that was what you were referring to.

Comment: My code is very large .... I took the part I want to adjust ..... what are you looking for in my  whole code? @RaffaeleSantoro

Comment: @Brain You should write a minimal working example when asking https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140722 and have a look and search in the pgfmanual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf and VisualTikZ http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf

Comment: @BlackMild I think I inverted my triangle and this is my trial (working example) and I found a problem though in the arrows and this is why I posted my question.

Comment: @Brain: I have edited your question. You can see what is a MWE: from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and its figure

Comment: you should consider answers on your very similar question. Actually, this one is duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this code

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 
\tikzset{midarrow/.style={postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,% switch on markings
            mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{latex}},
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate= -90]
\path
(0,0) coordinate (v3) node[left] {$v_3'$}
(0,2) coordinate (v0) node[right] {$v_0$}
(2,0) coordinate (v1) node[left] {$v_1'$};
\end{scope}

\draw[midarrow] (v3)--(v0);
\draw[midarrow] (v0) to node[right]{$a$} (v1) ;
\draw[midarrow] (v3) to node[left]{$b$} (v1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```